# How do i use data from an mysql result as table name

Tags: php, mysql

I know this code will be terrible but is there a way to use the result from a mysqli_fetch_assoc as the table name in another query?

This is what i have. Please someone tell me what im doing wrong

```
<?php 
   //this is where i set up the $_SESSION['userId']
   $result = mysqli_query($acctCon,"SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$safeEmail'");
   $assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   $_SESSION["userId"] = $assoc["id"];

   // this is what im trying to fix
   $safePost = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['post']);
   $user = $_SESSION['userId'];
   mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO $user (status) VALUES ('$safePost')");
?>
```

Can someone please help me ?, its driving me nuts.

Comment: It seems fine to me. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: INSERT INTO $user (status) VALUES ('$safePost') ? You have tables for every user ? . $user parameter is $session_id ?

Comment: some very strange db design here

Comment: what do you guys recommend?

Comment: We recommend explaining the problem you are having. What is the error message?

Comment: One table with all users data and a filter column with the userid ... `SELECT status FROM userdata WHERE user_id = $sessionId`; `INSERT INTO userdata (status, user_id) VALUES ('$safepost', $sessionId)`

Comment: Thanks bg i might just do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the session and on same time you are using it. It is not going to work. Use this line before insert query: `$user = $assoc["id"];`

Please Use this code :

```
<?php 
   //this is where i set up the $_SESSION['userId']
$result = mysqli_query($acctCon, "SELECT id FROM users WHERE    email='$safeEmail'");
$assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$_SESSION["userId"] = $assoc["id"];
$user = $assoc["id"];
// this is what im trying to fix
$safePost = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['post']);
mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO $user (status) VALUES ('$safePost')");
?>
```